# Are there significant benefits for an external hard drive with power supply over a USB-powered version?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power, lifespan

USB-powered external hard drives are more convenient than enclosures with a power supply because there are fewer parts to carry around and fewer power outlets necessary to use them. Is there a reason to prefer external hard drives with their own power supplies? [Durability](https://superuser.com/questions/601209) perhaps?

Comment: USB powered means a 2.5" drive (and probably 5400 rpm), whereas external power usually means a 3.5" drive.  The 3.5" drive is probably a faster drive, but probably not as robust as a2.5" laptop drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference between them.  As sawdust said, externally powered drives might contain faster drives.  Also, externally powered drives will stay powered if, even if the USB hub it is connected to cannot provide enough power.